# Current density limits?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electric-current, conductors

I am currently trying to design an air core electromagnet with a spiral coil topology which will be custom made from very high purity copper. Unlike standard wires, this coil is just a piece of copper without any insulation.

I have been trying to compute the maximum magnetic flux density for various current values, but there is one limiting factor which I cannot entirely justify - the current density limits proposed by various online sources, ranging from the standard AWG limits for copper conductors, to magic numbers without any explanation such as 500 A/cm^2.

Does a current density limit actually exist, or is it dissipated heat the "real" limiting factor, and those current densities are mentioned just to make it easier for circuit designers? In other words, does copper or some other conductor material have a limit to how much current can flow through it, or is it whatever keeps it below its melting point, and thus it all depends on how much heat I can remove from the coil?

Comment: Yes, there's a limit. Not only will Joule effect melt the wire and then you need a way to keep the liquid in place, but the magnetic field will torn away the wire itself due to lorentz force. There's a limit of how many Tesla can be made with pure copper without destroying the pure copper coil, it is roughly 20 T or so. You can go much higher if you don't care if the coil turns into a plasma, but I don't think that's your goal.